# How to prevent the running of auto macros when starting ms word in c++ automation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ms-word

I'm generating thumbnails for office files using c++. I open and save the files using automation similar to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179494. Since there are many files, this takes a lot of time and the program should run through the night.

Everything works fine, except when a file contains an auto start macro, which doesn't even exist.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Application.Run ("stupidMacroWhichDoesntExist")
End Sub
```

In this case, the Loop stops, and an error message appears that the macro couldn't be executed.

Off Course, I have set the macro settings in the trust center to -> disable all macros without notification

The error message still appears

In Excel, I can prevent this with:

```
objExcelApp.SetEnableEvents(false);
```

Unfortunately, the word application in c++ doesn't have a SetEnableEvents method. I have googled a lot and found a lot of VB Code to prevent this. Mostly it was something like:

```
objWord.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1
```

But I haven't found anything in c++

I'm very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for:

```
WordApplication.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

The Trust Center setting doesn't apply to documents being opened using automation. This property and its MsoAutomationSecurity enumeration correspond to that setting in the object model.

FWIW the WordBasic approach should also be possible using C++. I don't know C++ syntax, but with C# I'd need to use PInvoke (GetType().InvokeMember) to communicate directly with the IDispatch (I think that's the right term).

Comment: Thank you, but in c++ the WordApplication does not have a member called "AutomationSecurity". Btw, I am using the "msword8" IDispatch wrapper classes.

Comment: Why such an old type library? That's *really* old, like 20 years. AutomationSecurity post-dates that by a good decade. If that's where you have to be then you have no choice but going the WordBasic route.

Comment: The code of the whole program, which is hundreds of thousands lines big, reaches back to Windows 3.11 or even DOS. If I change to a newer library, that results in a big change and testing of the rest of the program.

Comment: Then you have no choice... Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of any C language other than C#. Would PInvoke sample code in C# help you? (And next time you will please remember to mention which library you're using when asking a question, right :-)? No one likes wasting their time working on an problem only to find out a key piece of information was missing!)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I'm backing up the actual macro (vbaData.xml and vbaProject.bin in the word folder), put a dummy macro into the word file, open it via automation and save it to generate the thumbnail. After that, I put back the backed up macro into the word file.
Since the dummy macro does nothing I am safe that nothing will be executed, whatever is programmed in the original macro.